# Getting the rolling.sum of row values with irregular time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex, rolling-sum

I am trying to get the rolling.sum of my time series. However, the rows have varying time intervals (see below my df_water_level_US1 dataframe):

```
    DATE    TIMEREAD    WATERLEVEL(M)   DateAndTime
0   01/01/2016  0:00:15 0.65    01/01/2016 0:00:15
1   01/01/2016  0:10:14 0.65    01/01/2016 0:10:14
2   01/01/2016  0:20:11 0.64    01/01/2016 0:20:11
3   01/01/2016  0:30:12 0.66    01/01/2016 0:30:12
4   01/01/2016  0:40:12 0.64    01/01/2016 0:40:12
```

and so on.
I tried to use this to get the sum for each day and save it to final_1D:

```
final_1D = df_water_level_US1.set_index('DateAndTime').rolling('1D').sum()
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: window must be an integer 0 or greater
```

The expected output is:

```
DATETIMEREAD   WATERLEVEL(M) DateAndTime
01/01/2016     3.24         01/01/2016
```

and so on (02/01/2016, 03/01/2016 etc)

Anyone who have idea how to fix this?

Comment: How wide do you want the sliding frame and what is the expected output. This would make your question more clear :)

Comment: Are you sure you want a rolling sum? Or just a sum per day?

Comment: @JakobGuldbergAaes Hello. :) I edited it and put in the desired output. By the way I need daily sum of the water level :)

Comment: @Paul sum per day will do :)

Comment: See my answer, however this is **not** a rolling sum (see info on rolling sum: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df_water_level_US1['DateAndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_water_level_US1['DateAndTime'])
final_1D = df_water_level_US1.resample('D', on='DateAndTime')['WATERLEVEL(M)'].sum()

print(final_1D.reset_index())

# Output
  DateAndTime  WATERLEVEL(M)
0  2016-01-01           3.24
```

The first line is not mandatory if your column `DateAndTime` is already a DatetimeIndex.

Comment: Thank you :) This worked :))) Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

For daily sum of water level try grouping by date:

```
df.groupby('Date').sum('WATERLEVEL(M)')
```

Comment: It did sum up but per time interval not the sum per day. The answer above worked. But still thanks :)